# Which combinations of NxN matrix rotations and horizontal / vertical flips result in the same outcome?

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations, rotations

I am doing an Advent of Code 2020 puzzle and currently trying to figure out which combinations of rotations and horizontal / vertical flips performed on an NxN matrix (2D array, really) result into a same MxM matrix.

For example, given this initial NxN matrix **A**:

```
#........#
........#.
#......#..
......#...
.....#....
....#.....
...#.....#
..#......#
.#.......#
#.#....###
```

If we rotate it 90 degrees CW, we get **B**:

```
#......#.#
.#........
#.#.......
...#......
....#.....
.....#....
......#...
#......#..
#.......#.
####.....#
```

Then again, we could do a series of other operations that also result in matrix **B**:

```
Initial
#........#
........#.
#......#..
......#...
.....#....
....#.....
...#.....#
..#......#
.#.......#
#.#....###

Rotate 90 (90)
#......#.#
.#........
#.#.......
...#......
....#.....
.....#....
......#...
#......#..
#.......#.
####.....#

Rotate 90 (180)
###....#.#
#.......#.
#......#..
#.....#...
.....#....
....#.....
...#......
..#......#
.#........
#........#

Rotate 90 (270)
#.....####
.#.......#
..#......#
...#......
....#.....
.....#....
......#...
.......#.#
........#.
#.#......#

Horz flip
#.#......#
........#.
.......#.#
......#...
.....#....
....#.....
...#......
..#......#
.#.......#
#.....####

Vert flip
#......#.#
.#........
#.#.......
...#......
....#.....
.....#....
......#...
#......#..
#.......#.
####.....#
```

So what I want to know is that which set of operations I have to do, to have gone through all the possible transformations of the initial matrix aka. which sets of rotate|flipVert|flipHorz transformations result in the same outcome and therefore can be left out?

Edit: Also, now that I think of it, does the order of these operations matter?

P.S I am a programmer, not a mathematician. I am guessing this probably has something to do with matrix transformations / linear transformations and perhaps even congruent shapes?

Comment: In general matrices do not commute, which means that if you change the order they will give different outcomes.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Nobody is multiplying matrices here; the matrices are just arrays of symbols without numeric meaning. So while operations do not commute, this has nothing to due with the matrices themselves not commuting for multiplication.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Yeah I too remember some pieces here and there from my linear algebra courses, one being AB != BA. Technically I think I could just switch those symbols with 1's and 0's and define rotation matrices and such, but eeeh.

Comment: Row and column operations can be done by matrix multiplication. The matrices that do so are called elementary matrices after the elementary row operations they pertain to. This can allow you to encode the information in a matrix and use multiplication to manipulate the symbols.

You can also note that these transformations preserve straight lines. This means there exist linear transformations to express them as matrices as well. In fact any finite group, including symmetry groups, can be represented using matrix multiplication.

In either case, $AB \neq BA$ most of the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking at is the [symmetry group of the square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)#Second_example:_a_symmetry_group), which has $8$ elements. Four of them are generated by a quarter turn rotation (the identity the rotation itself, a half turn and the rotation in the opposite sense), and the other $4$ can be obtained from these by composing each with the same reflection (it does not matter which one, as long as you use the same one). Say if I is identity, R the rotation, and H a horizontal flip I,R,RR,RRR,  H,RH,RRH, RRRH.
One has identities IX=X=XI for all X, RRRR=I, HH=I, and HR=RRRH (so indeed, order does matter here), which allow any combination of operations to be brought into one of these $8$ forms. A vertical flip V is just V=RRH and so does not add anything new. If you really need to know more about this, you will have to study a bit of group theory.

Comment: Amazing! This was exactly what I was looking for. I tried googling "matrix transformation equality" etc. and couldn't come up with anything useful, but this symmetry group of square is exactly what I needed. Thank you for those identity definitions as well, I was thinking something like that in my mind, but couldn't figure out how to write it down, so problem solving wise that is a great lesson. P.S You have a cool name, looking forward to white papers about "van Leeuwen symmetries" or something :)